# What's the term for an antonym of a continuum?

Tags: single-word-requests

Today I was trying to figure out an orthogonal word for "aesthetics", and was having a bit of trouble searching for it as "aesthetics orthogonal" and "aesthetics antonym" gave nothing useful—the latter just yielded synonyms to "ugly". (Didactic was the word I eventually settled on after coming up with it and double-checking the definition, but that's another issue)

"Orthogonal" would seem to be what I want, and as a scientist makes sense to me, but [another question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12219/usage-of-the-word-orthogonal-outside-of-mathematics) makes me think twice about using it in a broader context.

In short, what is the term for a word that would run along a different continuum that is perhaps related but distinct, for example:

- beauty vs. intelligence
- agility vs. power
- height vs. width

Comment: I'm not sure you are using *orthogonal* correctly.  Things are orthogonal when a movement along the axis of one things is completely independent of a movement along the other- in a graph the X and Y axes are orthogonal.  I might say that *utility* might be orthogonal to aesthetics in that how useful something is has nothing to do with whether it looks good or not.

Comment: A "branch concept"?

Comment: @Jim just like in mathematics, there can be many orthogonal vectors, utility seems orthogonal (to varying degrees...language is not math) to both aesthetics as well as the informational value (didacticisim).

Comment: @Jim the OP is using 'orthogonal' correctly. It is a dead metaphor of mathematical concept.

Comment: I think your "beauty vs. intelligence" example is pretty much the same as "aesthetics vs. intellectuality". Aesthetics pertains to pure emotion and sensation as opposed to logic and reason. That said, I think besides height vs. width, the examples are arbitrary. You could just as easily say agility vs. endurance, emotion vs. intelligence, etc. There's no real semantic relationship between the words, it's just arbitrary.

Comment: Words may or may not have antonyms; quite often they are multi-dimensional, so that "opposite" is meaningless in general. Here's [a sample ontology of verbs of cutting](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/cutting.pdf), for instance; most of them don't admit any "opposites".

Comment: @Mitch- I agree that later on in the question OP seems to have lit on the proper usage.  But based on the Title and in the first part of the question it seems like OP is using the word *orthogonal* to mean *antonym*.

Comment: You are creating [false dichotomies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_dichotomy).

Comment: @NickT The OP said "related but distinct". Orthogonal means they're unrelated.

Comment: It might help to put the word “aesthetics” into the title. Currently, it looks like you want a word that means the opposite to “continuum”, such as _point_ or _discrete set_.

Comment: Could be looking at **trade-offs** of one quality with another.

Comment: There is some confusion here for antonym vs. orthogonal by the OP, and a good example sentence may clarify. Most of the answers seem to chase one goal or the other.

Answer (score 2):

*[Orthogonal](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/orthogonal#Adjective)* indeed seems suitable, particularly when taken in its sense “Of two or more problems or subjects, independent of or irrelevant to each other” or perhaps in its sense “Statistically independent, with reference to variates”.  The zero-inner-product sense also will seem appropriate to people familiar with mathematics.

However, the term *[complementary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complementary#Adjective)* might be more useful, due to its common sense of “Acting as a [complement](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complement#Noun)”, that is, acting to complete something else.   Also consider *[tangential](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tangential#Adjective)*.

Regarding something orthogonal or complementary to *[aesthetics](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aesthetics#Noun)* (“The study or philosophy of beauty”), consider *[pragmatism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pragmatism#Noun)* (“The pursuit of practicality over aesthetic qualities; a concentration on facts rather than emotions or ideals”), or the aforementioned *[utility](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/utility#Noun)* or its  philosophical form *[utilitarianism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/utilitarianism#Noun)* (“A system of ethics based on the premise that something's value may be measured by its usefulness”).

Answer (score 0):

**Measure**.

The effectiveness of a football player depends on both agility and power.  Those who *measure* high in effectiveness will typically have some balance of these two attributes.

Sexual attractiveness is hard to *measure* precisely, yet most people feel that beauty without intelligence is no more appealing than intelligence without beauty. A *measure* of sexual attractiveness is inevitably personal and subjective.

We define the "squareness" of the river barges as a *measure* of their length relative to their width.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest **analogous** here, but maybe I misunderstood your question.

"A word that would run along a different continuum" makes me think of **analogue** or **counterpart**.

Answer (score -1):

Might **dichotomy** be the word you're looking for?

Answer (score -1):

The early 20th century German Dada movement was a rejection of aesthetics.  *Dadaism,* would be, perhaps, on point.  The adjective form  is dadaistic.

Answer (score -3):

The word you are looking for maybe "intermittence" (or "interruption").