# What do the British mean by "bolshie"?

Tags: british-english, slang

In this week's edition of *The Economist* there is a review of Edith Pearlman's latest book of short stories. In it, the reviewer says the volume is

> characterised by prose that is **bolshie** yet nuanced, elegant but not fussy, stylish without being vain.

Dictionaries I've consulted* inform me that *bolshie* means "radical" or "left-wing." These don't seem productive contrasts to "nuanced" in my view. I surmise that *bolshie* has to mean more than the dictionary is telling me. If so, what?

*****<sup><sub>NOAD ("A Bolshevik or socialist"), TFD ("difficult to manage, rebellious; any political radical"), Random House ("Bolshevik"), Webster's 3rd New Int'l, ("Bolshevik"), etc.</sub></sup>

Comment: The Economist uses writers from around the world. Did you check where the reviewer lives?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Over 50 years ago I was perfectly familiar with the "playground slang" term ***bolshie*** meaning [*uncooperative, recalcitrant, truculent*](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=KT-cAQAAQBAJ&pg=PA30&dq=%22so%20bolshie%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xkbfVMjJH8q57gao8IGwBw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22so%20bolshie%22&f=false) (Oxford Dictionary of Modern Slang, 2010). That was long before I knew anything about the political etymology - which later knowledge hasn't significantly affected how I've used and understood the word over the decades.

There are probably still some Brits who see overtones of US ***commie*** in the term even today, but it's worth noting that there was no equivalent to [McCarthyism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McCarthyism) in the UK, and the British public at large never really perceived any threat from ["reds under the bed"](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/reds-under-the-bed).

It may also be worth noting [a couple of hundred written contexts](https://www.google.com/search?q=bolshie%20stroppy&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) where ***bolshie*** occurs in close proximity to [***stroppy***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stroppy) (**obstreperous** = bad-tempered and argumentative), very few of which carry any political overtones. In fact, I'd say the *adjectival* usage *("Why are you being [so bolshie?](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22so%20bolshie%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22so%20bolshie%22&tbm=bks&start=10)")* is effectively ["orthogonal"](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/orthogonal) (Def:3) to the much rarer *noun* usage *("They're just a bunch [of bolshies"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22of%20bolshies%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl))* that etymological dictionaries are always so keen to tell us about.

---

In OP's specific context I don't think there's *any* "political" connotation to the usage. The reviewer just means...

> *although superficially the prose appears to reflect nothing more than mindless hostility/negativity (towards **everything**), closer examination reveals evidence of a finely nuanced writing style.*

Comment: This illuminates the parts I need illuminated. Thanks.

Comment: @Robusto: I just couldn't pass up on the chance to use [*orthogonal*](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12219/) there! :) It might be useful to consider, say, the current use of ***lame***, which to most younger speakers has no connection whatsoever to physical disability (unlike ***gay***, which although it's starting to be used more often with no "homophobic" intentions, probably always involves at least *some* awareness of the background etymology).

Comment: I don't think any British person would assume "bolshie" meant anything like "commie" except when used in a political context. For example, if you talked about your "bolshie colleague", they'd just assume you meant your unco-operative, annoying co-worker; if you referred to a left-wing politician's "bolshie friends", that *might* be taken as meaning their commie chums, rather than their unruly chums; if you referred to their "bolshie principals", that would almost certainly mean their communist beliefs (since it's unlikely that you mean "unruliness as a matter of principal").

Answer (score 11):

Definitions from online dictionaries:

> - a bolshy person often argues and makes difficulties: *He's a bit bolshy these days.* - [[Cambridge]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/bolshy)
> - difficult to manage; rebellious - [[TFD]](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Bolshie)
> - difficult or rebellious - [[Wiktionary]](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bolshie)
> - stubborn, argumentative - [[Urbandictionary]](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bolshie)
> - deliberately creating problems and not willing to be helpful - [[MacMillan]](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/bolshie)

As in my comment we tend to use it colloquially when someone is being unnecessarily aggressive, argumentative or generally 'anti-' about something.

Although I am more inclined to agree with your original line of thought and substitute bolshie for radical; radical can be defined as thorough, complete, total, comprehensive, exhaustive, sweeping, far-reaching, wide-ranging, extensive v nuanced: subtle difference or distinction in expression, meaning, response. Which actually contrasts rather well.

Bolshie is a shorten version of Bolshevism which was a *radical* socialist movement formed in Russia early in the 20th century. Bolshevism and its forms has been used by numerous right-wing newspapers & politicians as an accusation against their left-wing counterparts more *radical* elements.  So much so that colloquially it has almost become a byword for *radical*.

Comment: So is part of it that someone as dogmatic as a bolshie refuses to see nuances, instead looking at the world in black and white, good and bad?

Comment: I am emphasizing that bolshie *can* mean radical and radical is pretty much an antonym of nuanced, therefore is contrasting to it.

Comment: Radical and nuanced aren't really antonyms, as far as I understand them.

Comment: I disagree, Looking at their definitions IMHO they 'pretty much' are. I say 'pretty much' as we do have to give the reviewer some  literary license.

Comment: @Robusto I think one needs to take account, which no one seems to have done of the aggressive way that the Bolsheviks gained power, over their rivals the Mensheviks. Aggro, disdain for correct procedure, the employment of naked power over principle, are all inherent to the idea of *bolshie*.

Comment: @Christopher: Hi Christopher. Nice answer! I edited your answer to make the definitions section more readable. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @ermanen Nice job, looks much better now. I need to take timeout to learn the markup here. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Bolshie is short Bolshevik which means socialist. It has come to mean contrarian, uncooperative, or inclined to protest; probably stemming from derisive descriptions of left wing movements that lash out against the status quo.

Comment: I upvote you, but with a slight hesitation. I think the truth lies somewhere between yours and @Fumble Finger's comment above.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real key meaning is "dogmatic" or perhaps "fundamentalist" which is the "perceived" position of Bolsheviks within the socialist movements of the early 20th Century -- as opposed to the Mensheviks and/or Social Democrats, for example. Whether or not it was fair to describe Bolsheviks as dogmatic, that is perhaps how the term in the UK came to mean hard-line, aggressive, etc. Obviously, dogmatic in politics could be taken as an antonym for nuanced. Bear in mind, of course, that socialism's right-wing opponents often could not (or would not) distinguish the various strands within the left, and would call even the most faintly progressive person a "bolshie." In North America, at least since WWII, the term Commie would be the derisive diminutive that would stand in for the UK-English Bolshie. In fact, over here, I've never heard Bolshie used in the more general sense of aggressive or hard-line.

Comment: where is "over here"? (UK, US or somewhere else?)

Comment: North America (Canada & US)

Answer (score 0):

As in Bolshevik, revolutionary and ergo in your face or dissenting.

Answer (score 0):

In the context above 'bolshie' means stubborn & argumentative, actively unhelpful. It does not mean radical. Although it may have originated from Bolshevik its use has transcended it's origins - i.e. people say it without necessarily having a grasp of its origins or radical left wing politics.

Comment: Hello Brian. Christopher has already said this.